# In che cosa consiste un "tetto a colombaia"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto la frase seguente:

> Anche le facce mi piacevano cosí, come le avevo sempre viste: vecchie dalle rughe, buoi guardinghi, ragazze a fiorami, **tetti a colombaia**.

Ho cercato alla voce "colombaia" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato l'espressione "tetto a colombaia". Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Curiosamente l'ho trovata sul libro [*Bed & breakfast. Francia 2006-2007*](https://books.google.es/books?id=ncjoYx0uZNcC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=%22tetto+a+colombaia%22&source=bl&ots=j4Z9I0EsJ3&sig=ACfU3U3xyKj5C0xm_xqb_31Lu0-QTg0MVg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiemL_MvPPhAhUs3OAKHbTQCZ4Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tetto%20a%20colombaia%22&f=false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'accezione 2b) di [*colombaia*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/colombaia/) su Treccani riporta:

> b. scherz. L’ultimo piano d’un caseggiato alto: stare, abitare in c.,
> in una c. (anche in questo senso, più com. piccionaia).

E per *[piccionaia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piccionaia/)* sempre Treccani riporta:

> **piccionàia** s. f. [der. di *piccione*]. – 1. Locale all’ultimo piano
> delle vecchie case, soprattutto di campagna, e spesso ricavato nel
> sottotetto, che serve all'allevamento dei piccioni (nei casi in cui a
> tale uso è destinata un'apposita sopraelevazione o un fabbricato a sé
> stante, si usa piuttosto il nome di *colombaia*). Per l’espressione fig.
> gettare o tirare sassi in p. (o in colombaia), v. colombaia.

Ecco un [esempio di tetto a colombaia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi5nIjTl7TiAhUFJFAKHR4GCRIQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alamy.it%2Ffoto-immagine-pigeon-e-sul-tetto-della-colombaia-contro-un-bellissimo-cielo-137751636.html&psig=AOvVaw272a7e_HAx11O6nmz6RK5t&ust=1558787772389956):

[image: tetto-a-colombiaia]

Era quindi un particolare tipo di tetto diffuso nelle case di campagna conformato in modo da poter consentire l'allevamento di piccioni e colombi.